# Mule database connector - Unable to find a mapping for type: CURSOR

Tags: xml, maven, mule

I am trying to call a stored procedure in Mule via the new Database connector

```
<spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <spring:property name="url" value="abc"/>
    <spring:property name="username" value="def"/>
    <spring:property name="password" value="ghi"/>
    <spring:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <spring:property name="initialSize" value="10"/>
    <spring:property name="maxActive" value="50"/>
</spring:bean>

<db:generic-config name="Database_Configuration" dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                   doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
```

And inside my flow

```
    <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query>{ CALL some_procedure(NULL, :resultSet1) }</db:parameterized-query>
        <db:out-param name="resultSet1" type="CURSOR"/>
    </db:stored-procedure>
```

When I try to run this flow, I get the following exception.

```
Exception stack is:
Unable to find a mapping for type: CURSOR (org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.type.UnknownDbTypeException). (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.type.CompositeDbTypeManager.lookup(CompositeDbTypeManager.java:87)
```

I am using Mule EE version 3.8. And my pom has the mule-module-db artifact defined.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use db:oracle-config instead of using the generic database config; this would resolve the issue if you are using >3.6 EE version of mule.

Comment: similar type of post in [mule forums](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/38853/call-oracle-procedure-returning-sys-refcursor.html)